# Footer' is not exported from './components/footer/Footer'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

When running the npm start command returns the error below, I am importing the file /components/footer/Footer.js into the file /src/index.js

```
//ERRO Failed to compile.
```

./src/components/register/Register.js Attempted import error: 'Footer' is not exported from '../footer/Footer'

```js
//Footer.js

    import React from "react";

    export default class Footer extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <footer className="footer">
          <div>
            <p> Snef Brasil </p>
          </div>
        </footer>
        );
      };
    }

//index.js

import React  from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.css'
import App from './components/app/App'
import {Footer} from './components/footer/Footer'
import {Header} from './components/header/Header'


ReactDOM.render(
   <App />,
   <Footer />,
   <Header />,
   document.getElementById('root'))
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use

```
import Footer from './components/footer/Footer';
```

as it is a default export.

Also, your render call should be

```
const app = (
<div>
    <App />
    <Footer />
    <Header />
</div>
);
ReactDOM.render(
   app,
   document.getElementById('root'));
```

One more thing, it seems your issue might be with `Register` component and not this one.

Comment: Can you share the folder structure that you are working with? Please update your question with the same.